# Using an android phone as a server for PC LAN gaming

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, lan

So me and my friend wish to play tf2 using our phones as the server when we are in college. We tried using WiFi hotspot on the phone to connect but couldn't find any way to forward a port. So we tried downloading the app- "Port Forwarder". That didn't work too(or maybe we are just idiots who don't know what we are doing).

Is there a way to play the game using our phones as a server? I have a rooted Moto g and my friend has an unrooted OnePlus Two.

Here is the app we used: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bherbst.net&hl=en